# ng serve --open reports port 4200 is already in use when it isn't

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I try to run my angular app using command

***ng serve -o --port 4200***

it shows the error like,

***Port 4200 is already in use , try different port***

But I checked that, there is no running process in that port using this command

***sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN***

I have also tried different ports but result is same showing that port is also in use.

When I tried dynamic port selection command ( --port 0 ) the app runs . But I must have to specify the port number.

I am using
Node version - 8.12.0
Angular version - 5.2.6
Angular CLI version - 1.7.1

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284953/why-does-port-3000-work-but-no-other-ports-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, it's a bad version of portfinder. Until they fix it, specify directly in devDependences:

```
"portfinder": "1.0.20",
```

Comment: Thanks , its working for me . Saved lots of time and effort

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error: ‘Port 4200 is already in use. Use ‘–port’ to specify a different port’, you might have left your Angular development environment without closing the node.js webserver’s port.

Here’s how you can close it without having to reboot your computer or change your application’s port.

**Step 1: Find the connection’s PID**

```
netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber
```

Example with its output:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :4200
```

and output is :

```
TCP   127.0.0.1:4200    0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING    10764
```

**Step 2: Kill the process using it’s PID**

```
tskill yourPID
```

Example:

```
tskill 10764
```

**Step 3: Restart your server**

You should be able to run it (using ng serve)

**Step 4: Stop your server properly**

Don’t forget now to close properly your server by using Ctrl + C and typing Y:

That’s it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `--port 4200`. By default angular cli will serve your angular app in port 4200.

Comment: I tried that . I also tried __npm start__ but no luck .

Comment: Can you kill all node.js server that currently running in your computer ?

Comment: Actually I deployed my app in an AWS EC2 instance and there is no other node service  running . The app is running fine locally but causing problem in EC2 .

Comment: @shohagsarkar So, you're using `ng serve` in a production capacity (on AWS)?

Comment: Not actually , I used the above command for simplicity . I used bellow command to run my app in background in AWS.

`forever start -c "node --max-old-space-size=8192" ./node_modules/.bin/ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --prod --aot`

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you have a server running somewhere. This can happen when you quit a terminal window without stopping the server, for example. Open a task manager, and kill any Node processes. That should clear things up. Restarting your computer should accomplish the same thing.