# angular - ANY port is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I will running with `ng s` or `ng serve`, any port is in use

I haven't project runing, I can put any port, the problem happen.

if I try another project in angular, works

for information the version

```
$ ng -version

Your global Angular CLI version (8.2.0) is greater than your local
version (6.2.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 10.16.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

Comment: Please read this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557986/ng-serve-open-reports-port-4200-is-already-in-use-when-it-isnt/57558427#57558427

Comment: @abolfazr any port happens, another angular project works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng serve refuses to use any port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561610/ng-serve-refuses-to-use-any-port)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57561610/5468463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switch 6 to 7 and, works

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^4.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
```

Comment: glad to hear that 

Answer (score 1):

Angular by default will serve application on port 4200. If this port is already in use (by Angular or by any other application), you need to specify a port on your own.

For instance:

```
ng serve --port 4201
```

This will serve application on port 4201 and you'll be able to open it.

Answer (score 0):

the default port is 4200 if you run two project of angular one of them must run in different port or maybe another process use this port

try this `ng s --port 3000` later your access to the project like this `localhost:3000`

this message

*Your global Angular CLI version (8.2.0) is greater than your local version (6.2.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.*

mean your project has been created by angular cli version `6.2.9` and local version of the cli is included in the `node_module` in case of the global angular cli has different version the local one will be use to run , generate ,build ... so your project will not break in case of the latest version of angular and keep running

Comment: The message about version, I know, the problem is, any port not works

Comment: did you try like `ng s --port 3000` this and get the same message  ?

Comment: in here the talk about a problem like this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4201#issuecomment-334748340 so you need to check all port and try to run the cli with admin privileges

Comment: there isen't port in use, I did the following test
- I runed the API in port 8080 - works
- I stoped 
- I runned angular ng s --port 8080 - I received the message port in use
- I runned the API in 8080 - works
- I stoped
- I runned another angular in port 8080 - works

Comment:  I have no idea about these ports thing , sorry